# Delete object in a has_many through relationship with :dependent => :destroy Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

Im working on a Rails app where users can create projects. There are two types of users `Admins` and `Collaborators`. Both Admins and Collaborators `has_many :accounts, through: :account_users`, where account_users is a join table. When Admins deletes their accounts, I also want to delete their created account and it's project, but I can't get this to work. My models currently looks like this:

```
class Collaborator < User
  [...]  
  has_many :account_users
  has_many :accounts, through: :account_users
  [...]
end

class Admin < User
  has_many :account_users
  has_many :accounts, through: :account_users, :dependent => :destroy
  [...]
end 

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]
  belongs_to :admin
  has_many :account_users
  has_many :collaborators, through: :account_users
  [...]
end


class AccountUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :collaborator
end
```

When a Admin users deletes it's account, only the row in the join table and user table is deleted, their projects isn't deleted.

Note, I use devise for handling authentication.

How could I solve this?

Comment: You have a mixed hash syntax: `through: :account_users, :dependent => :destroy` ...best to pick one or the other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a project association, so I'm thinking you could do it in one of two ways:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_save :destroy_projects

   private
   def destroy_projects
      self.projects.delete_all if self.destroyed?
   end
end
```

or

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]
  belongs_to :admin
  has_many :account_users
  has_many :collaborators, through: :account_users
  has_many :projects, :dependent => :destroy
  [...]
end
```

Comment: I was having this same problem with the ActiveRecord relations so I had to destroy the collection using `self.other.destroy_all`.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't quite get it to work. The problem isn't with destroying the accounts projects but the admins account (company could maybe be a better name for account). I tried your first approach like this: `after_save :destroy_accounts` and, `def destroy_accounts self.accounts.delete_all if self.destroyed? end`. But it doesn't destroy the associated Account.

Comment: I think I got it to work with a very similar solution to your first suggestion, but I used before_destroy instead of after_save, and some minor changes in the helper method: `def destroy_accounts
      accounts = self.accounts.where("account_owner = '#{self.id}'")
      accounts.destroy_all end`. I need to do some testing, but I think it will work. Is there any downsides with my solution?
    end